# upload JPEG on selenium, Upload image through Selenium webdriver

Tags: html, selenium

HTML Snipit:

```
 <form id="frmUploadVisualAsset" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="Post"         action="uploadVisualAsset" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input id="slideIdForAsset" type="hidden" name="slideIdForAsset">
    <input id="courseIdForAsset" type="hidden" name="courseIdForAsset">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">
    <div id="visualUploader" class="col-md-6 upload-360">
    <**button id="**btnSelectFile**"** class="btn blue btn-browse" type="button"    style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
    <button id="btnUploadCancel" class="btn btn-default btn-cancel hide" style="z-index:99999" type="button">
    <span style="display:block"></span>
    <span id="filePreview" class="file-preview hide">123.jpg (17 kb)</span>
    <span id="fileProgress" class="file-progress hide" style="font-weight:bold">    </span>
    <input id="filePath" class="uploaded-file valid" type="hidden" data-msg-required="File uploading has not been completed yet." required="" name="filePath" aria-required="true" value="" aria-invalid="false">
    <input id="imageWidth" type="hidden" name="imageWidth">
    <input id="imageHeight" type="hidden" name="imageHeight">
    <div id="html5_19vb34lfo1mbgnda11dh1gjq1li33_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5 hide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 15px; width: 92px; height: 34px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;">
    </div>
    </div>``
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btnSelectFile")).sendKeys("Pass Absolute Path of JPEG file");
```

Now click on the upload button.

Comment: I have already passed absulote PATH
framUploadVisualAsset.sendKeys(PROJECT_PATH + ASSET_PATH + "uploadtest.jpg"); }